# How to setup titan over hbase in a single node hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, titan

I have a single node hadoop and have installed hbase also on my ubuntu 12.04. Now i want to install titan over hbase. I have setup hadoop-1.0.3 and hbase-0.94.18 and titan/hbase-0.4.2

I have added a user mnit.My /usr/local/ folder contains hadoop2 , hbase2, titan2 .First i start my hadoop using command bin/start-all.sh and then i start hbase using command bin/start-hbase.sh . after it when i do jps i found the following :

```
mnit@aman:/usr/local$ jps
9921 DataNode
11386 HRegionServer
11041 HQuorumPeer
11537 Jps
11115 HMaster
10153 SecondaryNameNode
10252 JobTracker
9691 NameNode
10483 TaskTracker
```

now i start gremlin.sh in titan2 using command bin/gremlin.sh .
i applied the following commands

```
mnit@aman:/usr/local/titan2$ bin/gremlin.sh
gremlin> conf = new BaseConfiguration();
==>org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration@19288c2
gremlin> conf.setProperty("storage.backend","hbase");
==>null
gremlin> conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1");
==>null
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open(conf);

WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper  - Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

When i searched over this problem i found that there is a file named pom.xml but the titan that i have downloaded does not contain pom.xml. please tell me if this  is a problem due to pom.xml. or i am doing something wrong or there is some other issue.

Thanks in advance

zk is managed by hbase in my system. i have added the following line in bin/hbase-env.sh

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

the content of my hbase-site.xml is as follows :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
         <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.datadir</name>
        <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The error suggests that Titan can't connect to Zookeeper for some reason.  Is HBase managing ZK, or are you running a ZK ensemble separate from HBase (i.e. `HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false`)?  What is hbase-site.xml's `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort`, if using HBase-managed mode?  Any other info on your ZK config might be useful too.

Comment: @Dan LaRocque : i have edited my question. and added the required information by you there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your Titan and HBase configurations appear to be inconsistent.  Your hbase-site.xml overrides the default ZK port (2181) to 2222, but it seems you haven't told Titan to use this non-default ZK port by setting storage.port in your Titan config file.  Naturally, they can't talk to each other in that state.  This doesn't have anything to do with pom.xml.

By the way, please don't simultaneously crosspost to SO and the aureliusgraphs Google Group.  They're both good venues with slightly different purposes, but you seem to have just copy-pasted between this SO question and [your subjectless thread on the aureliusgraphs list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/JnxQdt4DgXk/ItsRsdxPybgJ).

Comment: Thanks sir. I changed the port number from 2222 to 2181 and added hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxn property in hdfs-site.xml and it works.